# Why does the value attribute from an input[text] is different from what the browser renders?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm getting this strange behaviour in a very specific set of inputs on one my applications. I create some inputs and I can see them as I created them on the Elements panel (google chrome), but the way the browser renders it is different.

Note how the input is renders with comma instead of a point, but the `value` attribute uses a point

[image: Note how the input is renders with comma instead of a point, but the <code>value</code> attribute uses a point]

When I get a referente to that element using the selector API, I get this:

[image]

A direct reference to the Dom Element will return `11,00`. The tag has `11.00` and jQuery returns the `11,00`. I've removed all js that interacts with this element (masks, events, etc) and the issue still happens.

I've been swearing at the DOM for a day and a half, but I know this is most probably an issue with my application. What bothers me the most is that the browser does not honor what I see in the elements panel.

This is the small piece of code that creates the element, stopped right before the tag is created. Note the variables values in the right panel: 
[image]

Could someone give me a hint about what could be causing this difference in between element, view and attributes? If possible, I'd like to know what/how this is happening in depth.

Thank you in advance

Comment: So looks like you have some sort of locale set

Comment: Are you sure it's not your Operating System's settings of how to display decimal point? If not OS, then Google Chrome's?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be OS related. I had this same issue trying to debug on both my mac and my linux machines.